# CSS Only Shows Up When I Manually Drag My Stylesheet Into Inspect Element In Browser

Tags: css

I'm currently working on a small graphic design portfolio. My css will only apply to my html if I manually drag it into inspect element in a web browser. I cant seem to figure out this issue. Would really appreciate some feedback

I've made sure my stylesheet is in the same folder as my index. I'm not 100% sure if I linked them correctly though in my html.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type=text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" type=text/css">
    </head>



   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,700');

body {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    background: #EFF1F7;
}

.content {
   grid-area: content;
  background: url(images/background-shapes.png);
  }
.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: linear-gradient(#fa5c98, #795ef8);
  rgba(249,107,142,1),
  rgba(218,103,230,1),
  rgba(130,125,253,1);
  justify-content: center;
 }
```

I'm trying to apply a linear gradient (Sorry about my css I couldnt figure out how to properly format it like my html)

Comment: If you open console while viewing your page, are there any errors/404s that would indicate that you've linked it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing a quote in text/css at the beginning try this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hopefully that answer helped if it was helpful please upvote